# Verify the error message displayed when username or password field is empty or incorrect

Tags: automated-tests

I'm new to Selenium. I'm writing test scripts for Login page and my question is: If Username & Password entered is incorrect & after clicking on login button will display an error message. I want to validate it through selenium that im getting that error message. I also want to display it on Console window. I tried using

```
WebElement ErrorMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Password cannot be blank')]"));
System.out.println("" +ErrorMsg);
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

[This is the HTML for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv2hK.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void adminLogin() {
        String usernameError = "username is empty";
        String passwordError = "password is empty";
        
        
        WebElement userBox = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        String textInsideUserBox = userBox.getAttribute("value");

        // Check whether User name field is blank
        if(textInsideUserBox.isEmpty())
        {
           System.out.println(usernameError);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Login");
        }
        
        WebElement passwordBox = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        String textInsidePasswordBox = passwordBox.getAttribute("value");

        // Check whether Password name field is blank
        if(textInsidePasswordBox.isEmpty())
        {
           System.out.println(passwordError);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Login");
        }
```